# Pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed

Tags: c++, list, class, pointers, iterator

For some reason I cannot use functions attached to the object I want to use. I added a comment to the line that is not working. As an error I get "Error; pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed" Please help

This is code in `dokter.cpp`

```cpp
    int counter = 0;        
    for (list<Wielrenner*>::iterator it = wielrenners.begin(); it != wielrenners.end(); it++){
        Wielrenner* wielrennerOB = *it;
        cout << "\nID: " << counter;
        cout << "List size: " << persons.size() << endl;
        
        wielrennerOB->print();  // This is not working
        counter++;
     }
```

This is code in `wielrenner.h`

```cpp
    #ifndef WIELRENNER_H_

    #define WIELRENNER_H_

    //#include <fstream>
 
    #include "persoon.h"

    #include "Onderzoek.h"

    class Wielrenner :
    public Persoon
    {
    public:
        Wielrenner(string, string, Adres, string, Datum, Datum, string, int, float, float, float,list<Onderzoek>* );
        ~Wielrenner(void);
        int     getLengte() const;
        float   getGewicht() const;
        float   getVo2max() const;
        float   getMaxVermogen() const;
        list<Onderzoek> getOnderzoekenList();

        void    setLengte(int);
        void    setGewicht(float);
        void    setVo2max(float);
        void    setMaxVermogen(float);
        void    voegOnderzoekToeList(Onderzoek);
        void    showOnderzoeksList();
        void    setOnderzoeksLijst(list<Onderzoek>&);
        void    print();
        void    printFile(ofstream&);


    private:
    int     lengte;
    float   gewicht;
    float   vo2max;
    float   maxVermogen;
    list<Onderzoek> onderzoeken;
    };

    #endif /* WIELRENNER_H_ */
```

code in `wielrenner.cpp`

```cpp
    using namespace std;
    #include <string>

    #include "Wielrenner.h"
    /*
    #include "Onderzoek.h"

    */
    Wielrenner::Wielrenner(string voornaam, string achternaam, Adres adres, string telefoon, Datum datumInDienst, Datum geboorteDatum, 
                        string persoonType, int lengte, float gewicht, float vo2max, float maxVermogen,list<Onderzoek>* onderzoeken)
            : lengte(lengte), 
        gewicht(gewicht), 
        vo2max(vo2max), 
        maxVermogen(maxVermogen),
        Persoon(voornaam, achternaam, adres, telefoon, datumInDienst, geboorteDatum, persoonType)
    {
    }


    Wielrenner::~Wielrenner(void)
    {
    }

    //setten van gegevens
    void    Wielrenner::setLengte(int newLengte){
    lengte = newLengte;
    }
    void    Wielrenner::setGewicht(float newGewicht){
    gewicht = newGewicht;
    }
    void    Wielrenner::setVo2max(float newVo2max){
    vo2max = newVo2max;
    }
    void    Wielrenner::setMaxVermogen(float newMaxVermogen){
    maxVermogen = newMaxVermogen;
    }
    void    Wielrenner::voegOnderzoekToeList(Onderzoek newOnderzoek){
    onderzoeken.push_back(newOnderzoek);            
    }

    void    Wielrenner::showOnderzoeksList(){
    int teller=0;
    
    for (list<Onderzoek>::iterator it = onderzoeken.begin(); it != onderzoeken.end();     it++){
        Onderzoek onderzoekOB = *it;
        cout << teller << " - ";
        onderzoekOB.print();
        teller++;
     }  
    }

    void    Wielrenner::setOnderzoeksLijst(list<Onderzoek>& newOnderzoeksLijst){
    onderzoeken = newOnderzoeksLijst;
    }

    void    Wielrenner::print(){

    cout << "(" << persoonID << ") Persoon: " << endl;
    cout << persoonType << endl;
    cout << voornaam << " " << achternaam << endl;
    adres.print();
    cout << telefoon << endl;
    cout << "Datum in dienst: ";
    datumInDienst.print();
    cout << "Geboortedatum: ";
    geboorteDatum.print();
    cout << "> Extra wielrenner gegevens: " << endl;
    cout << "Lengte: " << lengte << endl;
    cout << "Gewicht: " << gewicht << endl;
    cout << "vo2max: " << vo2max << endl;
    cout << "maxVermogen: " << maxVermogen << endl;
    }
    void Wielrenner::printFile(ofstream &myfile){

    myfile <<  persoonID << "\n";
    myfile << persoonType << "\n";
    myfile << voornaam << " " << achternaam << "\n";
    adres.printFile(myfile);
    myfile << telefoon << "\n";
    datumInDienst.printFile(myfile);
    geboorteDatum.printFile(myfile);
    myfile << lengte << "\n";
    myfile << gewicht << "\n";
    myfile << vo2max << "\n";
    myfile << maxVermogen << "\n";
    }
    // returnen van gegevens

    int     Wielrenner::getLengte() const{
    return lengte;
    }
    float   Wielrenner::getGewicht() const{
    return gewicht;
    }
    float   Wielrenner::getVo2max() const{
    return vo2max;
    }   
    float   Wielrenner::getMaxVermogen() const{
    return maxVermogen;
    }
    list<Onderzoek> Wielrenner::getOnderzoekenList(){
    return onderzoeken;
    }
```

Comment: Usually I get this error if I have forward declared that class in the .h file and failed to include the full header file for the class in the .cpp file

Comment: Have you included the header? And have you made sure that no other header uses the same include guard (`WIELRENNER_H_`)? And is the class called `Person` or `Persoon`, or do you have classes with both names?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to include `wielrenner.h` in `dokter.cpp` .

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I don't think he's translating someone else's source code, I think he tried to translate his own source code to English for our benefit.

Comment: I just had this error, which I could not identify the reason for. It turned out it was some kind of issue with VS 2022. Restarted the IDE, then the error was gone.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

An "incomplete class" is one declared but not defined. E.g.

```
class Wielrenner;
```

as opposed to

```
class Wielrenner
{
    /* class members */
};
```

You need to `#include "wielrenner.h"` in `dokter.ccp`

Comment: I have done this class Wielrenner; at the header file for the cpp (where the code is)

Comment: @Sharpless512: `dokter.ccp` needs `#include "wielrenner.h"` in it, so that it knows the details of the class. It looks like `dokter.h` just has `class Wielrenner;` in it, hence the incomplete class error.

Comment: thanks for giving me the idea to find out the header file declare the function that triggered the error and include the header file

Comment: Note this also happens if you wrote the wrong name of the predeclaration and you imported that header file. Everything seems ok, but the predeclaration is not right :-)

Answer (score 18):

One thing to check for...

If your class is defined as a typedef:

```
typedef struct myclass { };
```

Then you try to refer to it as `struct myclass` anywhere else, you'll get Incomplete Type errors left and right.  It's sometimes a mistake to forget the class/struct was typedef'ed.   If that's the case, remove "struct" from:

```
typedef struct mystruct {}...

struct mystruct *myvar = value;
```

Instead use...

```
mystruct *myvar = value;
```

Common mistake.

Answer (score 8):

You get this error when declaring a forward reference inside the wrong namespace thus declaring a new type without defining it. For example:

```
namespace X
{
  namespace Y
  {
    class A;

    void func(A* a) { ... } // incomplete type here!
  }
}
```

...but, in class A was defined like this:

```
namespace X
{
  class A { ... };
}
```

Thus, A was defined as `X::A`, but I was using it as `X::Y::A`.

The fix obviously is to move the forward reference to its proper place like so:

```
namespace X
{
  class A;
  namespace Y
  {
    void func(X::A* a) { ... } // Now accurately referencing the class`enter code here`
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I came accross the same problem and solved it by checking my #includes.
If you use QKeyEvent you have to make sure that you also include it.

I had a class like this and my error appeared when working with "event"in the .cpp file.

myfile.h

```
    #include <QKeyEvent> // adding this import solved the problem.

    class MyClass : public QWidget
    {
      Q_OBJECT

    public:
      MyClass(QWidget* parent = 0);
      virtual ~QmitkHelpOverlay();
    protected:
        virtual void  keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event);
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem also occurs when header files are not included explicitly where they are needed, but implicitly through other heading files.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31860295)

Answer (score 1):

Check out if you are missing some import.