# How to fix "Pointer to Incomplete class type is not allowed" error in Unreal Engine 4

Tags: c++, pointers, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to learn C++ using a book called "Learning C++ by Creating Games with Unreal Engine 4" by Sharan Volin. Up to this point, I had been following the examples, but I got stuck at this error, despite the fact that I'm typing everything verbatim from the text. Is there something I am missing or not understanding?

I've tried to see if there were any other guides or Git Repos on this exercise, but had no luck. Other Stack user questions regarding error code E0393 (the error I'm getting) don't seem to help, as I have the `Avatar.h` file included in the `Avatar.cpp` file.

This is the code in the segment in the `Avatar.cpp` file giving me an error, specifically the last two lines that start as `PlayerInputComponent->`

```
// Called to bind functionality to input
void AAvatar::SetupPlayerInputComponent(UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent)
{
Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent(PlayerInputComponent);
check(PlayerInputComponent);
PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("Forward", this, &AAvatar::MoveForward);
PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("Strafe", this, &AAvatar::MoveRight);
}
```

This is some of the code present in the `Avatar.h` file, with only the last 4 lines being what I was instructed to type in.

```
public: 
    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

    // Called to bind functionality to input
    virtual void SetupPlayerInputComponent(class UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent) override;

    //New! These 2 new member function declarations
    //they will be used to move our player around!
    void MoveForward(float amount);
    void MoveRight(float amount);
};
```

The final result should allow me to move an avatar in the Unreal Project forward and to the right upon pressing "W" and "D" respectively. However, in the `Avatar.cpp` file, I get the error `E0393 pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed`. I also never get the project to launch in the Unreal Editor.

Comment: I literally googled for `PlayerInputComponent` and found the top search result is an **identical question** on another site.   Everything you need to know [is here](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/660205/view.html).  Short answer: `#include "Components/InputComponent.h"`

Comment: Read this answer as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027656/pointer-to-incomplete-class-type-is-not-allowed/12027678

Comment: Information that is provided by you is very vague and incomplete. Please provide more information. Or try solutions that are provided by other comments.

Comment: can you share the definition for `UInputComponent` ?It appears as though that class has not been defined.

Comment: *Learning C++ by Creating Games with Unreal Engine 4* -- I really wouldn't recommend learning C++ this way, to be honest with you.  API's assume that you know the computer language you're using already, and you're just learning about a framework and the functions/types involved in getting the framework going.

Answer (score 2):

simply go to your header file "Avatar.h" and type #include "Components/InputComponent.h"

Answer (score 1):

In your cpp file as you have forward declared the class. You need to have the include for the actual definition in the .cpp file.
So you need to have the include for the UInputComponent.

On the docs for the Component: [here](https://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/Components/UInputComponent/index.html) you will see at the bottom of the page it's location in the engines files.

`#include "Components/InputComponent.h"`