# Pointer to incomplete class type "SDL_SysWMmsg" is not allowed

Tags: c++, events, sdl, stylus

I try to get the hwnd handler from SDL focus event

I cannot compile this part with visual studio 2019

it says **pointer to incomplete class type "SDL_SysWMmsg" is not allowed** around **pMsg->**

```
if (e.type == SDL_SYSWMEVENT)
{
    SDL_SysWMmsg* pMsg = e.syswm.msg;
                
    if (pMsg && pMsg->msg == WM_SETFOCUS)
    {
        ...
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027656/pointer-to-incomplete-class-type-is-not-allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include that [header](https://happiness_follows.gitee.io/doc_translate/SDL2-2.0.7/html/de/deb/struct_s_d_l___sys_w_mmsg.html). Currently the compiler only knows, that `SDL_SysWMmsg` is a struct, and it is perfectly fine, when used as a pointer to a structure, because every pointer is just an address to the memory in the same format for all types ([read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c)). If you need to know the layout of the structure, then you need a definition of structure.