# Qt5: How do I use QPointer with Forward Declared class

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, forward-declaration

**The problem:**
Replace *naked pointers* with *smart* `QPointers` and use them with forward declared classes.

**Background:**
As advised by virtually all texts on modern C++, one should refrain from using *naked* pointers and use *smart* pointers instead. In the Qt toolkit there is a set of smart pointers available, with one of particular interest to me in this case: `QWeakPointer` (Qt 4) or `QPointer` (Qt 5), which is supposedly freely interchangeable with a *naked* pointer and is set to `NULL` when the respective object (derived from `QObject`) is deleted, thus helping prevent the all too common *dangling pointer* problem. Yet the requirement that the object pointed to by the `QPointer` be of a `QObject`-derived type prevents usage of forward declared classes.

**The question: How do I combine `QPointer`-type variables with forward declared classes in the class header with forward declared types?**

or

**How do I avoid including the whole header file for an object for which I want to use the `QPointer`?**

**Example:**

```
#pragma once
#include <QObject>
#include <QPointer>

class MyQWidget; // Forward-declared class

class SomeClass {
   QPointer<MyQWidget> m_myWidget;
};
```

**Note:** I've read through wuestion like this one: 
[In C++, is it possible to forward declare a class as inheriting from another class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159390/in-c-is-it-possible-to-forward-declare-a-class-as-inheriting-from-another-cla). In my question, I'm looking for Qt-specific ways to overcome this limitation (or better design feature), if there are any.

**Edit:** My main compiler is MSVC 2010 and the error I get is

```
error C2079: 'MainWindow::m_test' uses undefined class 'QPointer<T>'
    with
    [
        T=MyQWidget
    ]
```

Comment: Please add a `;` after the final brace of your class definition.

Comment: I can compile your example with Qt5 and mingw. What exactly is the message of your compiler ?

Comment: @fjardon: On MSVC 2010 I get: error C2079: 'MainWindow::m_test' uses undefined class 'QPointer<T>'
        with
        [
            T=MyQWidget
        ]

Comment: Make sure you have a constructor and destructor in your c++ file for your class. I assume from your error this is MainWindow.cpp. Also make sure that you also include the header for MyQtWidget in that cpp file. Although I usually use std::unique_ptr now instead of the any of the Qt pointers.

Comment: That is not the point which should be adressed here. The question is: why does the forward declaration not work? Cold you please share the declaration of MainWindow. Normally it should work as in your example above.

Comment: @drescherjm: I double checked constructors and destructors and even inclusion of the .h files, they are all present and I still get the error. I need the NULL on delete that comes with the QPointer, so I need a std:: pointer is not optimal here.

Comment: Are you sure you have included <QPointer> correctly? This seems to be the compiler not able to find QPointer instead of MyQWidget.

Comment: @fxam: I haven't, that was it. I'm on my way here to post all source code (as per comment from KimKulling) when I noticed my omission (I included the <QPointer> in a wrong file). Want to turn your comments to answer? Maybe it will be helpful for other lost soul as well...

Comment: You gave up too early, look: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-29588 (the question is absolutely correct, that is, only missing a compact self-contained source set to build)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure you have included QPointer correctly? This seems to be like the compiler not able to find QPointer instead of MyQWidget.

Comment: Wait what?
Thats the right answer? QPointer is included in line three.
Could the OP please clear up what was the problem, and how including QPointer "correctly" changed it.

Comment: I expect the example code did not match the actual code. Kind of hard to help in this case.

Comment: A -1 and a W-T-F indeed :)